# Why use a matrix?

Tags: matrices

Why would I want to use a matrix?  It's good for organizing a few numbers but I can't find too much use for them.  Could someone explain?

Comment: The  abstract idea about linear transformations is all well and good, but here are a few practical areas for application: Computer graphics (rotations, representing 3-dimensions in two dimensions, skewing images, etc) , probability, computer vision.  I had reason to use a $560\times 560$ matrix in a personal project studying the game of contract bridge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We use matrices to study linear transformations between vector spaces. In particular, suppose we have a linear transformation $T: V \to W$ between two vector spaces $V$ and $W$. Suppose we have an ordered basis of $V$ and an ordered basis of $W$. Then we can represent vectors in $V$ and $W$ as column vectors. We can then represent $T$ by a matrix.

Comment: This is so mathy... now is there a more intuitive answer for Why would I want to use a matrix?

Answer (score 1):

Matrices describe how transformations act on a space in a way that we can easily compute with. See this [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix#Uses).